# Existe alguma forma de pesquisar (FULLTEXT) em um campo específico no MongoDB?

Tags: mongodb

Eu tenho um índice full-text no MongoDB e preciso pesquisar apenas em cima de um campo, ao invés de todos. Alguém sabe se isso é possível?

Answer (score 1):

Conforme a [documentação do MongoDB](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/index-text/), o mesmo suporta a indexação e busca de texto a partir da versão 2.4, se ativada. A partir da versão 2.6, este recurso está disponível por padrão.

Para criar um índice texto, faça:

```js
db.reviews.ensureIndex( { comments: "text" } )
```

A engine de indexação de texto suporta várias linguagens, [listadas aqui](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/text-search-languages/#text-search-languages).

Para realizar a busca, use o operador [`$text`](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/text/#op._S_text), cuja sintaxes é:

```js
{ $text: { $search: <string>, $language: <string> } }
```

Answer (score 0):

Não tenho bons conhecimentos em MongoDB, mas este link irá lhe ajudar detalhadamente.

[Full text search in MongoDB](https://blog.serverdensity.com/full-text-search-in-mongodb/)